# Embedded Python Value Conflicts

Tags: c++, python, c

I'm using embedded python in my C program. The python script grabs a file from an online source and returns the data it received.

The C part of my program that envolves this particular script is the following:

```
char* Drop::getFile(std::string path){
  PyObject *pValue;
  char* fileData = NULL;
  pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule,"getFile");
  pArgs = PyTuple_New(1);
  PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs,0,PyString_FromString(path.c_str()));
  pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc,pArgs);
  fileData = PyString_AsString(pValue); 
  Py_DECREF(pFunc);
  Py_DECREF(pArgs);
  return fileData;
}
```

fileData does get a value, but the data it points to doesn't match what the python script pulled from the net. What I'm testing this on is a pdf file

> %PDF-1.4%âãÏÓ
>   194 0 obj<>endobj
>   xref
>   194 28
>   0000000016 00000 n
>   0000001374 00000 n
>   0000001521 00000 n
>   0000001915 00000 n
>   0000002047 00000 n
>   0000002547 00000 n
>   0000002661 00000 n
>   0000002773 00000 n
>   0000002800 00000 n
>   0000003401 00000 n
>   0000003656 00000 n
>   0000004166 00000 n
>   0000005703 00000 n
>   0000006124 00000 n
>   0000006373 00000 n
>   0000006828 00000 n
>   0000006898 00000 n
>   0000007022 00000 n
>   0000031268 00000 n
>   0000031531 00000 n
>   0000032131 00000 n
>   0000056344 00000 n
>   0000079808 00000 n
>   0000080674 00000 n
>   0000085029 00000 n
>   0000085946 00000 n
>   0000001196 00000 n
>   0000000873 00000 n
>   trailer
>   <> <6F4E88EE2CFAE8419CCB5AF471C4A73F>]/Prev 241987/XRefStm 1196>>
>   startxref
>   0
>   %%EOF
>
> 221 0 obj<>stream
>   hÞb`` `b ``YÇÀÆÀÀÆ È

But the actual file is much longer. I'm at a lost on why the data is being cut.

Comment: Why do you believe that the contents end there?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams Because I write it to a file and open it with a text editor and that's all that's there. I'm also unable to open it with my pdf viewer. Writing it out to a file in python works.

Comment: How do you write it to a file?

Comment: Does the file contain any NUL bytes? It might be C strings that assume NUL-termination that are biting you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `PyString_AsStringAndSize` and use the length of the file as well as the bytes returned. If you treat the returned bytes as a c-string, you'll interpret the first 0-byte as the end of the string.

In general, you must be careful when using string functions on binary data in C for exactly this reason.

Comment: `PyString_FromString()` is only being used to pass an argument to a Python function. And the argument (presumably a path given the the name of the variable) shouldn't contain any NULs.

Comment: yeah, it's the translation back -- he's interpreting the bytes returned as c-string.

Comment: @HadADat you might want to consider upvoting and approving the answer.

Comment: @Anonymous It doesn't allow me to. Not enough rep.